# Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for 'id' of 'Address' class

Tags: typescript, typegraphql, ts-node-dev

```
import { ObjectType, ID, Int, Field } from 'type-graphql';
@ObjectType()
export default class Address {
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: String;

  @Field()
  type: string;

  @Field()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  location: string;
}
```

info: ts-node-dev ver. 1.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.0.5)

while starting applciation using this command `ts-node-dev --respawn server.shop.ts`
I have got following error. (Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for 'id' of 'Address' class.)

Comment: Looks like `ts-node` has some isssues with `id: String;` - can you try with a lowercase `id: string;` like the other properties?

Answer (score 5):

add

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface and decorate it with the `@InterfaceType()` decorator

```
@InterfaceType()
abstract class IAddress {
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  type: string;

  @Field()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  location: string;
}
```

Then implement it in your Address class like this

```
@ObjectType({ implements: IAddress })
export default class Address implements IAddress {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  title: string;
  location: string
}
```

Read more on defining interfaces [here](https://typegraphql.com/docs/interfaces.html#defining-interface-type)